# Fix absolute and relative path using MAMP

Tags: php, class

I have a PHP class which has a private variable `path`. This variable is initialised with the class -

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PrePress/';
$temp = new Template($path);
$temp->head("Login", "");
```

Class template-

```
public function head($title, $js_scripts) {
        $path = $this->path;
        if($js_scripts == NULL) {
            $add_script = "";
        }
        echo "<head>
        echo    "<link rel='stylesheet/less' type='text/css' href='".$path."less/bootstrap.less'>
                 <link rel='stylesheet/less' type='text/css' href='".$path."less/prepress.less'>
                <script src='".$path."js/less.js'></script>";
        echo    $add_script;
        echo "</head>";
    }
```

The `$path` variable in the `<link>` does work however, the URL is altered with `http://localhost:8888/$PATH`, which is not found.

Because i am using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]`, I do not want the `localhost in the front of the URL. How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Some concatenation issues fixed

```
     echo "<head>
            <link rel='stylesheet/less' type='text/css' href='".$path."less/bootstrap.less.css'>
            <link rel='stylesheet/less' type='text/css' href='".$path."less/prepress.less.css'>
            <script src='".$path."js/less.js'></script>
            ".$add_script."
            </head>";
```

Comment: What is your full path?

Comment: /Users/Namit/WEB/PrePress/

Answer (score 0):

Replace code

```
echo "<head>
   <link rel='stylesheet/less' type='text/css' href='".$path."less/bootstrap.less'>
             <link rel='stylesheet/less' type='text/css' href='".$path."less/prepress.less'>
            <script src='".$path."js/less.js'></script>";
    echo    $add_script;
    echo "</head>";
```